# Why are there no icons on the Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, gnome, compiz, nvidia

Due to my graphics card being blacklisted, I had to "force" Compiz and Unity to run. After doing so the Ubuntu Classic environment works awesomely (as my card supports it fully), and Unity works very well too-- except that there are no icons on the launcher. I can still run things from it but there are no icons. How can I fix this? [I'm using the nVidia Experimental 3D driver and the 173 (proprietary, I only installed it thinking it would fix the issue)]

This is on a Toshiba Tecra M2 (the old one :P)

Comment: what's your graphics card?  `lspci | grep VGA`

Answer (score 1):

If your card is blacklisted, there is a good reason. The likely problem here is that your card does not support a feature that Unity needs. I would suggest you report a bug.

For now, you can still enjoy Unity by using Unity 2D. You can even run it under compiz.